# Using 'each' is sometimes mandatory, sometimes not with CSV

Tags: ruby, loops, csv, each

I am using the csv gem, following [this web site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php).

Once I evaluate `CSV.parse`, it is mandatory to use `each` to loop over the resulting `Array`. This works:

```
csv = CSV.parse("1,2,3")

csv.each {|row| print row, ", ", row.class, ", size ", row.size, "\n"}
```

while this does not work:

```
csv {|row| print row, ", ", row.class, ", size ", row.size, "\n"}
```

When directly using the form `CSV.parse`, either using `each`:

```
CSV.parse("1,2,3").each {|row| print row, ", ", row.class, ", size ", row.size, "\n"}
```

or not:

```
CSV.parse("1,2,3") { |row| print row, ", ", row.class, ", size ", row.size, "\n"}
```

gives the same result. Why?

Comment: It is not clear which part of your code correspond to which part of your question. Can you cut your code apart into small pieces?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could point out which *precise* part of [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse) is unclear to you. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation for future readers.

Comment: @sawa - Updated question as per your comment.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - I am a beginner with Ruby. Please see my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly explained [in the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse):

- `CSV::parse` when called with a block iterates over the rows.
- `CSV::parse` when called without a block returns an array of rows (which you can then iterate over).

Comment: On one hand, I was not completely sure I grasped the description in the documentation. With that sloppy understanding (and considering that my Part 1 is your 2nd case, and viceversa), it *seemed* to me that in your 1st case, `.each` would not work, as `CSV::parse` is already iterating.

Comment: If you are familiar with languages like C++, Java, C♯, etc., you can think of this as two different "overloads" of the same method. This is not possible in Ruby, of course, Ruby doesn't support overloading, but a method can inspect its own arguments and execute different code paths depending on what it finds. Almost all iterator methods will return an iterable object if you don't pass a block.

Comment: You can see the actual code here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/csv.rb#L1312